# Finding the power

Tags: c

Write a C function which accepts a positive integer, n, and returns 2^n. State any assumptions made.

So is this correct....??

```
#include<math.h>
double power(int x)
 {
     int i,pow,n, ans;
     ans=1;


     printf ("Enter the number and power:");
     scanf ("%d%d", &pow, &n);

     for(i=1;i<=pow; i++)
     {
       ans = ans *n                    
        return pow(2,n);
      }




    int main ()
    {
       int x, y,c;
       c=pow(x,y);

       printf("%d to the power %d is %d",n,pow,ans);
       getch();
```

}

Comment: already tried what? there is simply a function prototype but no actual code to perform the task... what have you tried so far? SO is not about us doing your homework...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, what you want is simply to do 2^n. p^n will never exists.

```
 #include <math.h>
    double two_pow_n(int n){
      return pow(2, n);
    }
```

Comment: I corrected my answer.
I mean that he will never ask his function for somtheing like 3^5, the first parameter is fixed to 2.

Comment: The first character of an identifier can't be a digit, you'll need to change that function name to something like two_pow or pow2.

Comment: You're right, a simple rule I forgot. Edited.